# How to read file posted with FormData through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to see if a file is correctly posted from my form but everything I try to echo/print shows up empty.

This is my form:

```
<form id="employeeformadd" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card m-b-20">
          <div class="card-body">
            <input type="hidden" name="id_company" value="<?PHP echo $getbedrijfinfo['id']; ?>">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card m-b-20">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Kopie rijbewijs</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <form action="#">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="copy_driverslicense" type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false" data-buttonname="btn-secondary">
                    </div>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Kopie paspoort</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <form action="#">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false" data-buttonname="btn-secondary">
                    </div>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Kopie medische geschiktheidsverklaring</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <form action="#">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false" data-buttonname="btn-secondary">
                    </div>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Diploma</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <form action="#">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false" data-buttonname="btn-secondary">
                    </div>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And this is my jquery:

```
$("body").on("click","#addemployeebtn",function(){
    var form = $(this);
    var formdata = false;
    if (window.FormData){
        formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
    }

    var formAction = form.attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        url         : 'includes/addemployee.php',
        data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
        cache       : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        type        : 'POST',
        success     : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // Callback code
        }
    });
});
```

And in my php script I have tried these things:

```
echo = $_FILES['filename'];
echo $_POST['file'];
print_r($_FILES);
echo $_FILES['file'];
echo $_FILES['files']['name'][0];
```

But they are all empty when I echo/print them.

If I look in the networktab I see the form is posted so my javascript works.

Comment: Where you _echo/print them_?! that should be in success callback when it's empty

Comment: Which content-type do you use for sending the form data (browser dev tools > network tab)? if you use `application/form-data` (could be automatically set when using FormData objects) the data will not be stored in `$_POST` or `$_FILES`.

Comment: include the screen shot of networktab result

Comment: @Dormilich The request header content type is: `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarys18zjsPqBUzWkP6u` and the response header is: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: @twan Then there will be nothing in `$_POST` and `$_FILES`. You need to parse the raw input to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're binding click event to a button `$("body").on("click","#addemployeebtn",function(){` BUT referencing `$(this)` object as a form by doing `var form = $(this);`.

So its either you bind a `submit` event to the form id or reference the form object form the form id `var form = $('#employeeformadd');`.

Also, you need to remove all the sub forms you have inside the main form `<form action="#">` and remember to remove their closing tags too `</form>`.

**Most Importantly:**

Add `name="fieldname"` to your file field like this `<input id="copy_driverslicense" type="file" class="filestyle" data-input="false" data-buttonname="btn-secondary" name="photo1">`

Comment: Everything is still empty after I try this.

Comment: I've edited my answer and I think it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

at the first you should replace $("body").on("click","#addemployeebtn",function() with 
$("body").on("submit","#employeeformadd",function()

so when you write  var form = $(this); the form object refer to #employeeformadd form not #addemployeebtn submit button

and second you should give name to each input file for example

so in php you can access it by write  $_FILES['diploma'];

and finally you should remove unnecessary form tag in your html for example